# print works but rospy.loginfo doesn't

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have this code and print would work but rospy.loginfo

```
 import rospy

from std_msgs.msg import String
messageToRos = Queue.Queue()

def writeMessageToRos(messageToRos):
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        msg = messageToRos.get()
        print 'new messageToRos: ', msg
        rospy.loginfo('new messageToRos: ', msg)
        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()
```

even the publisher works fine. How would I correctly do a loginfo or debuginfo for msg ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268370/print-works-but-rospy.loginfo-doesn%27t/) by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2017-08-09**:
Are you running this from `rosrun` or `roslaunch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @vKuehn,

I made a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCLcftHHrEs) that answers exactly this question.

In summary, in order to make `rospy.loginfo` print on the screen, if you are running the node with `roslaunch`, you must use the parameter `--screen` when calling `roslaunch`, or add the `output="screen"` on your launch file.

For example:

1 - `roslaunch your_package your_launchfile.launch --screen`

or

2 - `<node pkg="your_package" type="your_file.py" name="your_file" output="screen"/>`

On the video I explain step by step.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2017-08-09**:
that sounds promising thanks will look at the video. is there a way to do that setting right in the python file ?

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-08-09**:
You're Welcome.

Well, I've never done this using directly the `pytyon` file.

But with the steps mentioned on the answer (and explained on the video) works perfectly ;)

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2017-08-09**:
just saw the video. What a rooky problem. You answer is however excellent ! thanks for the video

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-08-09**:
You're Welcome.

Glad to help you.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-09**:
Why not explain step-by-step here? The problem with linking to a video for more steps is that now part of the answer is external and this answer is not self-contained. What if the video gets taken down?

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-08-09**:
The "step-by-step" is already on the answer.